# joomla error and I cant go in my site

Tags: php, joomla

Fatal error:

Class `'JError'` not found in

`/home/memogift/public_html/administrator/includes/framework.php on line 18`

How to solved this issue ?

Comment: you should visit this first
http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You are missing some core joomla files. Upload again all the files and install.